# How do I populate my Date Dimension Table in SQL Server so as to get a column with this specific value?

Tags: sql-server, date, dimensional-modeling

I have the following query that runs in SQL Server 2014 to populate a table called DateDimension.

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime
   DECLARE @enddate datetime
SET @startdate = '01/01/2000'
   SET @enddate = '12/31/2018'
DECLARE @loopdate datetime
   SET @loopdate = @startdate
WHILE @loopdate <= @enddate
   BEGIN
INSERT INTO DateDimension VALUES (
   Day(@loopdate),
   Month(@loopdate), 
   Year(@loopdate), 
   CASE WHEN Month(@loopdate) IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 3 -- Since Financial Year starts in July, January to March is considered as Quarter 3
   WHEN Month(@loopdate) IN (4, 5, 6) THEN 4
   WHEN Month(@loopdate) IN (7, 8, 9) THEN 1
   WHEN Month(@loopdate) IN (10, 11, 12) THEN 2
   END,
   @loopdate,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@loopdate,111) 
   ) 

   SET @loopdate = DateAdd(d, 1, @loopdate)
   END
```

Extract of current table, after running the above query is as follows:

```
id  Day Month   Year quarter    date        datevarchar
1   1   1       2000    3    2000-01-01       1/1/2000
2   2   1       2000    3    2000-01-02       1/2/2000
3   3   1       2000    3    2000-01-03       1/3/2000
4   4   1       2000    3    2000-01-04       1/4/2000
5   5   1       2000    3    2000-01-05       1/5/2000
```

I need the "quarter" column to show its values as below:

```
   quarter
  Qr 3 2000
```

It would be even nicer if the "quarter" column be left as-is and a new column added to show what I'm after. How can I do this?

Comment: By concatenating with 'Qr' and the Year.   Very basic.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you have a *specific* problem? You already have a script that generates values. All you need to do is to add another column to the table and the proper expression in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the column on to the DateDimension table first before running the query.  It will be a varchar(9) column.

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime
   DECLARE @enddate datetime
SET @startdate = '01/01/2000'
   SET @enddate = '12/31/2018'
DECLARE @loopdate datetime
   SET @loopdate = @startdate
WHILE @loopdate <= @enddate
   BEGIN
INSERT INTO DateDimension VALUES (
   Day(@loopdate),
   Month(@loopdate), 
   Year(@loopdate), 
   CASE WHEN Month(@loopdate) IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 3 -- Since Financial Year starts in July, January to March is considered as Quarter 3
   WHEN Month(@loopdate) IN (4, 5, 6) THEN 4
   WHEN Month(@loopdate) IN (7, 8, 9) THEN 1
   WHEN Month(@loopdate) IN (10, 11, 12) THEN 2
   END,
   @loopdate,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@loopdate,111),
   CASE WHEN Month(@loopdate) IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 'Qr 3 ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),Year(@loopdate))
   WHEN Month(@loopdate) IN (4, 5, 6) THEN 'Qr 4 ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),Year(@loopdate))
   WHEN Month(@loopdate) IN (7, 8, 9) THEN 'Qr 1 ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),Year(@loopdate))
   WHEN Month(@loopdate) IN (10, 11, 12) THEN 'Qr 2 ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),Year(@loopdate))
   END
   ) 

   SET @loopdate = DateAdd(d, 1, @loopdate)
   END
```

Comment: Great! Highly appreciated!